# Restore files in a git-folder

Tags: git, github

I am in big trouble, as I was working on a project and all files are gone in the very moment, where I wanted to store them into a remote repository.

Here is what I did:
I have a project, let's say in folder C:/project/
Then I created a remote repository and wanted to push my files to it.
I use the tool Git Extensions for Windows.
I created a new repository inside my project-folder. Immediately it sayd I should stage 1000+ files. So I staged them. Then I wanted to push them, so I had to set up the remote-repository, which I did.
Afterwards it showed that the staged files were on a different branch, so I switched to remote-master. Then I wanted to merge with the staged files, but they were not there anymore. So I wanted to switch back, but the other branch was not there anymore. All my previous files are gone. I tried to checkout local-master with no success.
Is there any way to get all my files back, or did I really delete them all? Maybe just resetting the whole repository?

I'd really appreciate your help here.

Greetings
Chriz

Comment: Before anything else, make a full copy of your project directory. Your files might still be in your `.git` folder but they might be elligible to deletion.

Comment: Then try command `git reflog`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Comment: You seem to be right, the project-folde still takes around 3Gb of size. Backed it up now. `git reflog` showed me a lot of _checkout: moving from master to master_.

Comment: It also displays the corresponding commit ids which enables you to checkout from one to another. Try to checkout before the first `moving from master to master`. Good luck.

Comment: You Sir, are my hero today. Everything is back! Could you maybe post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? This is the least I can do for you as you saved me around 1 month of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, git stores every versions of your files under the `yourProject/.git/` folder.

It is possible to rollback to previous commits even if git history was altered by commands such as `reset --hard`, `commit --amend`, `rebase` etc thanks to the `reflog`.

**Disclaimer :** when git history is altered, some commits might be in a detached state which makes them elligible for garbage collection. Before going further, it is **strongly recommended** to **backup** the whole project directory or those commits might be permanently lost.

From [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) :

> Reference logs, or "reflogs", record when the tips of branches and other references were updated in the local repository.

The command `git reflog` shows the modifications that were made in the history. This enables to `git reset` to the desired state and rollback an unwanted git history alteration.

**Example :**

- I create an empty repository
- I create a file `test.txt` with the content `hello`
- I commit it
- I append the text `world` to `test.txt`
- I amend the commit (this does not modify the previous commit but actually create a new commit. The previous commit still exists but is in detached state).
- I use `git reflog` to find the previous commit.
- I use git reset --hard to restore the previous commit.

**Output :**

```
/tmp/test [ mkdir /tmp/test
/tmp/test [ cd /tmp/test
/tmp/test [ git init
/tmp/test [ echo 'hello' >> test.txt
/tmp/test [ git add test.txt
/tmp/test [ git commit -m 'First commit'
[master (root commit) 60292e4] First commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt
/tmp/test [ echo 'world' >> test.txt
/tmp/test [ git commit --amend -m 'oops'
[master 76ce76f] oops
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt
/tmp/test [ git reflog
76ce76f HEAD@{0}: commit (amend): oops
60292e4 HEAD@{1}: commit (initial): First commit
/tmp/test [ git reset --hard 60292e4
/tmp/test cat test.txt
hello
```